# How do I print colored text in IDLE's terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, python-idle

This is very easily a duplicate question--because it is. However, there are very many inadequate answers to this (e.g. try `curses`! -- pointing to a 26 page documentation).

I just want to print text in a color other than blue when I'm outputting in IDLE. Is it possible? What's an easy way to do this? I'm running Python 3.6 on Windows.

Please explain with an example.

(I have found that ANSI codes do not work inside IDLE, only on the terminal.)

Answer (score 19):

Put this at the "start" of your code:

```
import sys

try:
    color = sys.stdout.shell
except AttributeError:
    raise RuntimeError("Use IDLE")
```

And then use `color.write(YourText,Color)` for "printing":

```
color.write("Hi, are you called Miharu461? \n","KEYWORD")
color.write("Yes","STRING")
color.write(" or ","KEYWORD")
color.write("No\n","COMMENT")
```

This prints:

[image: Prints]

---

**Note**: this does NOT automatically puts the enter (like in the `print` function/statement). So, when you are printing put `\n` at the end of the last string to put it.

The "Colors" you can put are: `SYNC`, `stdin`, `BUILTIN`, `STRING`, `console`, `COMMENT`, `stdout`, `TODO`, `stderr`, `hit`, `DEFINITION`, `KEYWORD`, `ERROR`, and `sel`.

**Note 2**: This is dependent of the color scheme you are using for IDLE. So I recommend you to use it for highlighting, and not for making a program for asking what in color is some word.

Comment: This also prints the number of characters printed with `color.write` immediately after the printed string. Is there a way to only print the string?

Comment: Use `\n` as an Enter key. Example: `color.write("Foo\n","STRING")` works like print. Also, `color.write` is the name I gave it because I put `color = sys.stdout.shell`. You can use anything instead of "color".

Comment: That wasn't my question. There's extra unexpected output using the `write` method: it prints the number of characters in the string immediately after the string. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: At least on my computer, it doesn't print that. I added a picture of the output I get in the answer.

Comment: What I see is a blue number directly after the output that's the total number of characters printed. So like, there might be a 38 printed after "No" if I tried running this. (I just counted...I don't know if it's exactly 38)

Comment: If you are getting a number at the end of your output then assign it to a variable e.g : `a = color.write("Yes","STRING")`.

Comment: Thank you @JuanT for this solution!

Learning Python with the kids and expanded on your explanation as colorama and ANSI codes not working in Python 3.8.2 IDLE terminal.  To help out others:

**Script 1**
`import sys
try: color = sys.stdout.shell
except AttributeError: raise RuntimeError("Use IDLE")

White="SYNC"
White2="stdin"
Purple="BUILTIN"
Green="STRING"
Orange="console"
Red="COMMENT"
Aqua="stdout"
White3="TODO"
Pink="stderr"
HighlightWhite="hit"
Blue="DEFINITION"
Rose="KEYWORD"
HighlightPink="ERROR"
HighlightGrey="sel"
`

Comment: **Script_2**
`from Script_1 import *

color.write(f"Your random text goes here:\n",HighlightGrey)`

Comment: @BlackThunder if you aren't planning on using the variable it's better to use `_`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `clrprint` module to print color text in idle, Terminal and Powershell too.

Install:

```
pip install clrprint
```

Usage:

```
from clrprint import *
clrhelp()  # to see colors available
user_input = clrinput('INPUT MESSAGE', clr='green')  # just like input()
clrprint('YOURTEXT', user_input, clr='color')  # just like print()
```

Comment: It would have been better if you didn't use the `from [...] import *` syntax, because i make complicated to know what come from the module.

Comment: While this might work, it heavily depends on a particular hilight color setting being available in the IDLE configuration.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Why does writing to stdout in console append the number of characters written, in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047368/strange-output-when-writing-to-stdout-in-console) "... write will also return the number of characters (actually, bytes, try sys.stdout.write('へllö')) As the python console prints the return value of each expression to stdout, the return value is appended to the actual printed value."

Use

```
_ = color.write("Hello world","COMMENT")
```

to "eat up" the extra output. `_` is a "throwaway" variable, see [What is the purpose of the single underscore “_” variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163)

Comment: if you aren't planning on using the variable it's better to use `_`.

Comment: @Seth Thanks for the hint - I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The strnage output of the length is with the `return` keyword, and `NORMAL` is also a color

Answer (score -1):

The problem I faced was how to output error messages in IDLE properly, since `sys.exc_info()` is printed like normal output while `traceback.print_exc()` is a bit of too long and detailed. So, I just want to print the Exception in red color like "traceback".

Thanks the top anwser for letting me learn about specifying the type of my messages with write(). Accidentally, I've found another method that meets my demmand by simplely adding `file=sys.stderr` while print(). Then I'll get a striking but brief error messages. An example in python 3.6:

```
import sys
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e), file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Hi @yawn, it looks like this does not answer the question. Please keep in mind this is not a forum, so only post an answer if you have something that can actually solve the OP question.

Comment: Sorry, @toti08, I think I just follow the ruler "Provide details and share your research!" and my method does achieve printing colored text other then blue in IDLE's terminal. Please let me know how to adjust my answer, thank you very much.