# How to colour Python output (version 3.6.3 IDLE)

Tags: colors, python-3.6

I have already searched the web far and wide but I can not find a valid answer for my problem (for Python 3.6.3 IDLE).
I'm creating a program with IDLE Python and i need to change the output colour to green (0,255,0).
Can you help me? :D

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472958/how-do-i-print-colored-text-in-idles-terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

IDLE is written in Tkinter so it uses the same techniques that
you would use to change the colour of text in a Text widget.
But IDLE does not expose the Text widget to you as a user.

In fact it doesn't make much sense for IDLE to do that since IDLE is
only a development tool. It is not where you are expected to run
your programs. THus IDLE tries to mimic the environment where
your programs should run not to provide facilities that would
only work within IDLE.

Is there any reason why you want to change the ouput only in IDLE?
Or do you really want to be able to control the output of your
program wherever it runs? If the latter then you will need to
create your own Text window and display the output there.

By this Method some how you can change color.but add Extra Character by itself, it mean it is not efficient

```
>>> color.write("Hi, are you called Miharu461? \n","KEYWORD")
Hi, are you called Miharu461? 
31
```