# Using Colorama on Python 3.7 on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get a portion of my code to print out in color using colorama. I have:

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
init(convert=True)
print(Fore.RED + 'Hello')
```

but the code output has no color change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What console are you using? Does it support ANSI codes for coloring?

Comment: @AdamSmith I am honestly not sure.. I am very new to this. I am in IDLE right now for 3.7.2 which is where my file is.

Comment: Just tried this code in window 10 default terminal, and it is running file, in spider it is not working as expected, in pycharm terminal it is working , in pycharm python console it is not working

Comment: @Andrea it sounds like your code is working fine, but IDLE does not support ANSI color codes. Terminals are a whole kettle of worms that's way out of scope here.

Comment: @AdamSmith Oh, okay thank you, I did not know that. Is there anyway I can print colored text from a file in IDLE (IDLE is required by my course).

Comment: You can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472958/how-do-i-print-colored-text-in-idles-terminal but it sounds like you're doing the right thing and shouldn't worry about trying to get it to work in IDLE. IDLE isn't the best IDE (by a long shot) though it's better in recent years.

Comment: @AdamSmith, okay, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It works without init(convert=True). you should use init()

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
init()
print(Fore.RED + 'Hello')
```

Comment: Try and explain why removing this parameter works so that the person who asked this question actually understands the problem

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal Thanks for the explanation. I'm setting it up now